# couldn't get lock for .log file in Java

Tags: java, logging

I am using Logger **from Restlet framework** with FileHandler to log my application in production mode. However, I always get the Excetption "Unable to create a FileHandler for the Logger: Couldn't get lock for test.log". How can I solve this?
Here is the code:

```
FileHandler aFileHandler = new FileHandler("test.log");

Formatter aFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();

aFileHandler.setFormatter(aFormatter);

aLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

aLogger.addHandler(aFileHandler);
```

This log file is used by several by more than one process at the same time.

And except the .log file, a lot of other files like ".log.1, .log.2 ....." have been created. Does anybody know why?

Comment: You might want to give some more details on the exception you're receiving, and perhaps supply some bits of code showing the relevant bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide full Class Names. `Logger` & `FileHandler` are ambiguous. However I guess you are using some kind of logger maybe Log4j and a RollingFileAppender which is why your files are getting rotated i.e. xxx.log.1 & xxx.log.2. 
Your file is being used by some other process/application which is why you are not able to get a lock on that file.

Comment: So you mean if I change the .log file name, this problem will be solved?

Comment: You have to provide more details. Please share the code showing the Logger and FileHandler piece as mentioned by @posdef above

Comment: Don't understand the solution too.

Comment: cud u elaborate? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I too got the same error, but when I checked the path of the file, it was wrong so after correcting the path it worked fine. Just check the path if it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For question about "a lot of other files like ".log.1, .log.2 ....." have been created", you have to remove the log filehandler and close it after you dont need it. 
Here is the code for your reference.
        `log.removeHandler(fileHandler);
        fileHandler.close();`

Comment: I tried this and the effect is that none of the log entries are present on the file until I stop or restart tomcat. At that time, (most of) entries appear on the file, but some are lost. Is there a command that could force the logger to write before releasing the handler?

Answer (score 0):

For me, The logger didn't have write access to the directory in which the log file is about to be created. Therefore I just changed the path to somewhere that a full access was guaranteed (e.g. `FileHandler aFileHandler = new FileHandler("D:\\test.log");` and the issue went away.

I'm guessing that in may case because I hadn't had specified any particular file path (like `FileHandler("test.log");`, after deploying my web service using tomcat, the log file was trying to be created in `Catalina base directory` or somewhere which has no write access.