# Issue in FileHandler

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize a FileHandler to write to the given filename, with optional append using the foll syntax:

```
FileHandler fh = null;
fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New_folder\\logs\\slate\\TodayLoad-2013-10-24.log",true);
```

But I'm getting the exception as:

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for  C:\Users\Desktop\New_folder\logs\slate\TodayLoad-2013-10-24.log
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at TodayLoad.Load.<init>(SlateSheetLoad.java:173)
    at TodayLoad.Load.SlateSheetLoad.main(SlateSheetLoad.java:423)
```

How can I solve this issue.

Comment: does another process have the file open?

Comment: where is your file be used beside this?

Comment: Try opening the File with Notepad, try to modify it. If this fails, check why.

Comment: @all : Another process does not have this file open an I tried opening this file in notepad and modified it without any issues.

Comment: Is the path **C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New_folder\...** correct? That implies that multiple users have access to the file path. I expected a path such as  **C:\\Users\\A_Particular_User\\Desktop\\New_folder\...**.

Comment: There may be a lock held by a process you are unaware of. For example, by Notepad or by the process that wrote or copied the file. You could test by restarting Windows then running the FileHandler code. Another alternative is to use LockHunter to verify that the file isn't locked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file is getting accessed by another process.
See this post that can help you
[couldn't get lock for .log file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700752/couldnt-get-lock-for-log-file-in-java)

Comment: I checked this post and gave the fuuly qualified class names and checked the file path as well but getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that you get the error after 100 log files have been written. The root cause is a bug in Java. See, for example,

[System Property Controls the java.util.logging.FileHandler's MAX_LOCKS Limit](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8193696)

and

[Increase java.util.logging.FileHandler MAX_LOCKS limit](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8153955)

These references also suggest a solution: set the system property "jdk.internal.FileHandlerLogging.maxLocks" well before the code that does the logging. For example, by means of

```
 // Set maxLocks to 200. The default is 100.
 System.setProperty("jdk.internal.FileHandlerLogging.maxLocks", "200");
```

Comment: I set this property in my startup script but it doesn't have any effect. I'm still getting the same error with maxLocks=100.